# Externalising app context and hibernate.properties from the war

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat

I have externalised the config files from a war, and I was wondering how to resolve the absolute location I am being forced to provide in the app context in order to get it to work.

In my web.xml I have this -

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>file:C:/Program%20Files/somedirectory/webappContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

C:/Program%20Files/somedirectory/webappContext.xml has an entry as below:

```
<import resource="applicationContext-persistence.xml" />
```

application context - persistence.xml is present in the same directory as webAppContext.xml and it has a line -

```
<util:properties id="hibernateProperties" location="hibernate.properties" />
<encryption:encryptable-property-placeholder encryptor="stringEncryptor" location="hibernate.properties"/>
```

Tomcat is unable to find the hibernate.properties file located in the same directory. Instead it forces me to define it as below:

```
<util:properties id="hibernateProperties" location="file:C:/Program%20Files/somedirectory/hibernate.properties" />
<encryption:encryptable-property-placeholder encryptor="stringEncryptor" location="file:C:/Program%20Files/somedirectory/hibernate.properties"/>
```

Is there a way to get around specifying the full path? Why does line in webAppContext.xml work and not the lines in applicationcontext-persistence.xml? Both are similar in nature as in referencing files located in the same directory.

Comment: although they might appear the be similar they aren't. You could try prefixing with `./` but I doubt that works.

Comment: tried that. Doesn't work. 'file:./' , './' none work. and Definitely 'classpath:hibernate.properties' will not work either as the program files/somedirectory is not in the classpath of the tomcat container

Answer (score 1):

The `webappContext.xml` should reside in the WAR, but it can contain something like:

```
<bean id="coreProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:/properties/*.properties</value>
            <value>file:${app.home}/properties/*.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

 <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="false"/>

    <property name="properties" ref="coreProperties" />
</bean>
```

Now you only have to pass the `app.home` System Property when the application starts:

```
# cat setenv.sh
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Dapp.home=/home/user/my-app"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to cheat the framework, and it does not want to help you to do it.

More seriously, it is the way that resources are resolved in an application context. Extract from [doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#resources-implementations) for current version of Spring Framework :

```
Prefix      Example                        Explanation
classpath:  classpath:com/myapp/config.xml Loaded from the classpath.
file:       file:///data/config.xml        Loaded as a URL, from the filesystem
http:       http://myserver/logo.png       Loaded as a URL.
(none)      /data/config.xml               Depends on the underlying ApplicationContext.
```

As you are using a WebApplicationContext (normal for a web app ...), unqualified resources will be searched under the root of the application.

But that is not all, same doc says later :

*The FileSystemApplicationContext simply forces all attached FileSystemResource instances to treat all location paths as relative, whether they start with a leading slash or not. In practice, this means the following are equivalent:*

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("conf/context.xml");
ApplicationContext ctx = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("/conf/context.xml");
```

That means that without using a custom ResourceLoader you cannot use relative paths and have to use `file:full_path_to_file` as soon as your resources are not inside the war.

Anyway, you surely do not really want to do that : your war now cannot be deployed in any other system that your own server ! It is indeed possible to have (small) parts of configuration outside the war itself, it it has sense because some elements may only be known at deploy time. There are two portable ways to do it :

- use environment variables as they can be used to resolve placeholders in spring configuration : this is mainly used for simple configuration data : webmaster email, mail server, URL for a backend, or for dynamically choosing between different [profiles](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-environment)
- use servlet container configuration and JNDI : this is often use for database configuration